# There is a vertical tabular menu in Semantic-ui (90º rotated)?

Tags: menu, tabs, semantic-ui

Is it possible to do a tabular menu like this one in Semantic?[Example vertical tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpcPC.jpg)

Comment: create a `ul li` menu in CSS and rotate it using `transform: rotate(-90deg);`